# How can I get other person's packets over Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

First of all, my aim is not to do any illegal things.

What does a person need (environment, tools) to catch incoming or outgoing frames from any other person's device which is in the same network? For example, sending login information to a server and I want to catch these frames.

What capabilities are needed for this? How is a person called in the hacking scenario? Man in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually referred to as "sniffing". A "man in the middle" can not just eavesdrop but also censor or change any data which is transmitted.

By default, a network adapter only listens to network frames which are addressed to it. But most network adapters can be switched into "[promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode)" which allows them to capture any frames. In most wired networks this won't help you much because nowadays most LANs are fully switched. This means that the switches already make sure that no host receives any frames they are not supposed to receive (although in some cases it might be possible to trick switches to send frames to the wrong host by using [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing)).

It will, however, work in WiFi networks where switching is technically impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing you'll need is direct access to their un-switched LAN, and a NIC Card that can go into promiscuous mode. Then... you need to do [a LOT of reading](https://www.wireshark.org/download/docs/user-guide-a4.pdf).

It would probably also help to have a background in networking. The "Attack" in this scenario is known as packet sniffing/analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to carry out an ARP spoof, where you send out a malicious ARP entry stating that the gateway / router is you to all the clients and then you inspect that data then send it to the real gateway, essentially all data has to pass through you.
For starters the best tools for this exist in Linux:

1. Turn on IP forwarding then arpspoof the clients through the commands: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward, man arpspoof to get to know what arguments it receives
2. You can overload the switch's CAM table through a CAM overflow attack such that the switch just forwards all data, here's  a [tutorial][1]
3. You can establish a rogue DHCP server through a Linux program called yersinia, but this requires bridging to the real gateway
4. Another Linux tool called Ettercap

These tools are all Linux based, and you have to open Wireshark to see what is going on.
 But just in case you want to do it from a Windows machine, look at 2 tools called **Nighthawk** and **Cain and Abel** but I would recommend going the Linux way.

Comment: Your methods carry some significant impacts to network performance. If the OP is not looking to do anything illegal, then it must be mentioned that these actions are not passive and could get him fired.

Comment: thats not my on my moral conscience,thats on his I just answered the question @schroeder

Comment: That may be true, but it is important to highlight the issue so that they know that they have a choice to make. If the OP is unaware and blindly followed your steps, he would be in big trouble.